# stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document selenium webdriver in chrome browser

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, webdriver

i am learning selenium when i am executing following selenium program(selecting expected date from datepicker) i am getting stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document. I have gone through some online solutions but it is not working at the same time. I think while executing my program it is not finding the elements in DOM. Please guide me with the solution. Thanks in advance.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;

public class skyscanner_datepicker 
{
@Test
public void calender_func() throws InterruptedException
{           
    String expected_date = "January 2018";
    String expected_day = "15";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D://rakesh//software//selenium browser//chrome 2.30//chromedriver.exe");
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    driver.get("https://www.skyscanner.co.in/");
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.findElement(By.id("js-depart-input")).click();
    Thread.sleep(3000);     
    if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover skyscanner-datepicker depart']//span[@class='current']")).getText().equals(expected_date))
    {
        System.out.println("Date selected in if condition");
    }
    else
    {
        for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
        {                       
        try 
        {
                driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover skyscanner-datepicker depart']//div[@class='calendar-info-bar datepicker_clearfix']//button[2]")).click();               
                if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover skyscanner-datepicker depart']//span[@class='current']")).getText().equals(expected_date))
                break;
                System.out.println("date get selected");                    
        } 
        catch (Exception e) 
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }   
        }           
    }

    List<WebElement> day_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='container-body']//tbody//tr//td"));
    for(WebElement a : day_list)
    {
        if(a.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(expected_day))
        {
            a.click();
        }
    }       
    driver.quit();
}
```

}

Comment: At which line are you seeing `stale element reference: element is not attached to the page document`?

Answer (score 0):

I guess that in this loop:

```
for(int i=1;i<=12;i++)
{                       
try 
{
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover skyscanner-datepicker depart']//div[@class='calendar-info-bar datepicker_clearfix']//button[2]")).click();               
        if(driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='popover skyscanner-datepicker depart']//span[@class='current']")).getText().equals(expected_date))
        break;
        System.out.println("date get selected");                    
} 
catch (Exception e) 
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}   
}
```

you are trying to wait for same date value to appear in the element.
**It almost never worked! Use explicit waits instead.**

---

Familiarize yourself with:

- [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) class
- [Wait#until](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html#until-java.util.function.Function-) function
- [ExpectedConditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) factory methods (most used wait conditions)

and use this snippet instead of the above loop:

```
// wait up to 30 seconds
WebDriver wait = new WebDriverWait( driver, 30 );
final By element = By.xpath("//div[@class='popover skyscanner-datepicker depart']//span[@class='current']");
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.textToBePresentInElementLocated( element, expected_date ));
```

This will wait for 30 seconds for date to appear in the element, if the value does not become visible within 30 seconds, then timeout exception will be thrown.

---

This code retrieves all elements, then is looking in a loop for only one element, then is trying to click it:

```
List<WebElement> day_list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[@class='container-body']//tbody//tr//td"));
for(WebElement a : day_list)
{
    if(a.getText().equalsIgnoreCase(expected_day))
    {
        a.click();
    }
}
```

But why don't just look for this concrete element to become visible and clickable ?
Use this:

```
final String elementXpath = String.format(
    "//div[@class='container-body']//tbody//tr//td[ contains( ., '%s' ) ]",
    expected_day ); 

final By elementToClick = By.xpath( elementXpath );

// wait until element appears and becomes clickable, then click it
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable( elementToClick )).click();
```

Answer (score 0):

StaleElementReference exception could have been caused when webdriver tries to access the element while the page is still loading. Try adding page load time out after you initialize you webdriver.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

This will tell the webdriver to wait for upto 5 seconds for the page to load before moving to a next page action.

Also, the number of seconds depends on the time to completely load the web page of your application

Comment: this code didnt resolved my problem. I am getting same error even by increasing seconds

Comment: Then, please share at which line of your code you are getting the error. You can see it in your console window of your IDE.